# Import bathemetry via csv and visualise a large body of water

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-visualization

I hope I explain this correctly.

I'm looking for a way to better visualise  underwater noise.
I'm not after a solution (well, maybe I am) but more interested in what the perfect start would be, considering speed is of essence (so pretty much your opinion of Q1 to Q3).

I’m trying perform calculations and visualisations of a body of water.
For this I want basically import the bathymetry (csv containing x,y,z) of a substantial area (lets say 50kmx50km).

Q1: do I use a pandas dataframe or numpy array.

Q2: do you envision this as a mesh, where the column names are x and row names are y and the elevation(z) are the fields?

As z can be positive or negative, the landmass starts when z>0, which will always vary depending on tide. I want to be able to increase or decrease the low and high tide on the ‘fly’
The actual seafloor bottom is also important depending on the surface, salinity, water temperature per meter ect.

Q3: is this where I should go 3D (in mesh?)

For now I was just focussing on importing the bathymetry and visualise what I imported in a graphical way (and failing a bit).
So far my code looks like below, sorry about the lack of comments.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import scipy
from scipy import interpolate

# min_? is minimum bound, max_? is maximum bound, 
#   dim_? is the granularity in that direction

filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=',',names=["X", "Y", "Z"])
df.sort_values(by=["X"])

mat = df.to_numpy()

min_x = np.array(df['X'].values.tolist()).min(axis=0)
max_x = np.array(df['X'].values.tolist()).max(axis=0)
min_y = np.array(df['Y'].values.tolist()).min(axis=0)
max_y = np.array(df['Y'].values.tolist()).max(axis=0)
min_Z = np.array(df['Z'].values.tolist()).min(axis=0)
max_z = np.array(df['Z'].values.tolist()).max(axis=0)
dim_x = np.array(df['X'].count())
dim_y = np.array(df['Y'].count())


x=df.columns[0:]
y=df.columns[1:]
z=df.columns[2:]

x = np.linspace(min_x, max_x, dim_x)
y = np.linspace(min_y, max_y, dim_y)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

#   Interpolate (x,y,z) points [mat] over a normal (x,y) grid [X,Y]
#   Depending on your "error", you may be able to use other methods
Z = scipy.interpolate.griddata((mat[:,0], mat[:,1]), mat[:,2], (X,Y),method='linear')

plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z)
plt.show()
```

Comment: As pandas already stores numerical data into numpy arrays, writing `np.array(df['X'].values.tolist()).min(axis=0)` is a horrible detour. Just use `df['X'].min()`. About speed, with lots of data `df.sort_values(by=["X"])` would take some time and probably isn't needed. Something you really should revise is using 'dim_x' as the number of subdivisions is both dimensions. That is way too high, and would stop your code from working when there is more data.  Using `round(sqrt(dim_x))` or that value multiplied by a small constant, would be more sensible.

Comment: Thanks @JohanC, I didnt realise pandas already stores numerical data into numpy arrays. I will try to come up with a solution for dim_x (it stops there even with sqrt) but not sure why. thanks for the info!

Comment: found my error, small test file was comma delimited, big one was tab, silly me